# Make Cesium full screen

Tags: angular, cesiumjs

I'm using Cesium to show a 3D model in a web-page developed with Angular. The problem is that when I click the button to make the viewer full screen, the background becomes black and the viewer doesn't stretch, exactly as explained in [this issue](https://github.com/articodeltd/angular-cesium/issues/158) on the Cesium-angular Git repo.

In my case the Cesium is defined in a directive in my Angular project and I call it in all the components I need by simply passing an attribute to the div. For instance:

```
<div [appCesium]="myResource.url + '/model.json'" class="cesiumContainer"></div>
```

In the directive instead I only defined the `ngOnInit` function which initializes the Cesiusm with certain parameters (zoom, animations and so on). I tried to add some lines of code suggested in the discussion I followed in the repo, at the end of the function, to test if the fullscreen would work and it worked indeed. The problem is that the model is displayed fullscreen when the cesium is initialized when I want to trigger this code by clicking the enlarge button provided by the Cesium viewer or (in alternative) disable the default fullscreen button and create a custom button to go fullscreen and run my code. Here's my code:

```
... viewer options settings ...
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer(this.el.nativeElement, viewerOptions);
... home button definition ...
... zoom button definition ...
// test of full screen code (which works)
const canvas = viewer.canvas;
if ('webkitRequestFullscreen' in canvas) {
    canvas.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else if ('requestFullScreen' in canvas) {
    canvas.requestFullScreen();
}
```

Any idea?

---

**EDIT**

At the moment I "fixed" the issue by adding a listener to the fullscreen button as follows:

```
viewer.fullscreenButton.viewModel.command.afterExecute.addEventListener(function() {
  const canvas = viewer.canvas;
  if ('webkitRequestFullscreen' in canvas) {
    // chrome
    canvas.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if ('requestFullScreen' in canvas) {
      // other browsers
      canvas.requestFullScreen();
  }
});
```

but there are two problems of this approach:

- Only the canvas is brought fullscreen. The widgets are lost.
- The "fullscreen" button icon on Cesium, after the first click will turn into the "exit fullscreen mode" and won't ever change back.

If any of you have a solution which works better for this problem, I leave the question open here.

Answer (score 0):

Today: June 25, 2022 my solution is to put the Canvas fullscreen in the beforeExecute AND the afterExecute
note canvas'webkitRequestFullscreen' is for avoiding transtyping in Typescript

```js
const fullScreenHandler = () => {
      const canvas = viewer.canvas;
      if ('webkitRequestFullscreen' in canvas) {
                canvas['webkitRequestFullscreen']() // Safari
            } else {
                canvas.requestFullscreen();
            }
        }
viewer.fullscreenButton.viewModel.command.beforeExecute.addEventListener(fullScreenHandler)
viewer.fullscreenButton.viewModel.command.afterExecute.addEventListener(fullScreenHandler)
```

Works in Safari, Firefox and Chrome based browsers (june 2022 versions)

Comment: I am trying to access the fullscreen functionality with  ol-cesium. It works but only in Chrome and Firefox, while in Safari it gives me problems. Do you have any suggestion? My code is here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74478054/ol-cesium-exit-fullscreen-mode-in-safari-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. I had to step up some html elements to get the right one. And I used Cesim.Fullscreen.requestFullscreen to apply fullscreen.

```
const fullScreenHandler = () => {
  const canvas : HTMLElement = viewer.canvas;
  let parentElement = canvas.parentElement;
  parentElement = parentElement!.parentElement;
  parentElement = parentElement!.parentElement;

  Cesium.Fullscreen.requestFullscreen(parentElement);
}

 viewer.fullscreenButton.viewModel.command.beforeExecute
.addEventListener(fullScreenHandler);

viewer.fullscreenButton.viewModel.command.afterExecute
.addEventListener(fullScreenHandler);
```