# ol-Cesium exit fullscreen mode in Safari doesn't work

Tags: openlayers, fullscreen, cesiumjs

I have an map projected with OpenLayer 6. I added a button to change to 3d view with ol-cesium.

When the map is in Cesium the fullscreen button of Openlayer is no more visible (which by the way works perfectly in all browsers when I am in standard OL 2d), as it happens with ol-controls. So I added a fullscreen button that appears only when in ol3d.
However, when I have ol3d activated, toggling between fullscreen and normal screen works fine only in Firefox and Chrome.
In Safari I can access the fullscreen, but I cannot exit (I have to use the keyboard esc). I don't understand where's the problem.

Here's my code

**HTML**

```
<div id="map" class="map">
  <div id="cesiumFs">                                                       
    <button id="cesiumFsButton" type="button" title="Toggle full-screen"></button>
  </div>

  <div id="CesiumEnable" class="cesium-icon-change-3d" title="Change projection">
    <i id="globe" class="fa fa-globe fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
const ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({
  map: map,
});

//set ol3d to false as normally I want the 2d map view
ol3d.setEnabled(false);

//when clicking on 3D I enable the Cesium view 
document.getElementById('enable').onclick = function() {

  //get the elements controlling Fullscreen mode
  let cesiumFsTrigger = document.getElementById('cesiumFs');
  let cesiumFsButton = document.getElementById('cesiumFsButton');

  //if ol3d is true
  if(!ol3d.getEnabled()){

    //when opening up Cesium I change zoom and center
    const NewView =  new ol.View({
      projection: mercatorProjection,
      center: ol.proj.transform([-80, 20], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 3,
      maxZoom: 15,
      minZoom: 0,     
      }); 
    map.setView(NewView);

       //set ol3d to true  
    ol3d.setEnabled(true);  

        //When in 3d add a "Fullscreen" icon in substitution to the OpenLayer interaction (otherwise not working with Cesium)
        //shows the new fullscreen button (set as active) 
        cesiumFsTrigger.classList.add('FsActive');

          //add a fontawesome icon
        cesiumFsButton.innerHTML = '<i id="toggleFs" class="fa fa-expand-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>';

        let iconFs = document.getElementById('toggleFs');
        let cesiumFsElement = document.getElementById('map');

          //set fullscreen mode to the map
        cesiumFsTrigger.addEventListener("click", () => {
          if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
            Cesium.Fullscreen.requestFullscreen(cesiumFsElement);
            iconFs.classList.remove('fa-expand-arrows-alt');
            iconFs.classList.add('fa-compress-arrows-alt');
  
          } else {
             if (Cesium.Fullscreen.exitFullscreen) {
             Cesium.Fullscreen.exitFullscreen();
             iconFs.classList.remove('fa-compress-arrows-alt');
             iconFs.classList.add('fa-expand-arrows-alt');
             }
             else if (Cesium.Fullscreen.webkitExitFullscreen) {
             Cesium.Fullscreen.webkitExitFullscreen();
             iconFs.classList.remove('fa-compress-arrows-alt');
             iconFs.classList.add('fa-expand-arrows-alt');
             }

          }
         });//close fullscreen conditions for icons 
  }
  else {
     //if ol3d is false
    ol3d.setEnabled(false)
    map.setView(view); 
    cesiumFsTrigger.classList.remove('FsActive');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found, which works perfectly

HTML

```
<div id="map" class="map">
  <div id="cesiumFs"></div>

  <div id="CesiumEnable" class="cesium-icon-change-3d" title="Change projection">
    <i id="globe" class="fa fa-globe fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
//the following code enables the change of view in 3D Cesium (ol-cesium)
const ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({
  map: map,
});
//set ol3d to false as normally I want the 2d map view
ol3d.setEnabled(false);

//when clicking on 3D I enable the Cesium view 
document.getElementById('enable').onclick = function() {

  //get the elements controlling Fullscreen mode
  let cesiumFsTrigger = document.getElementById('cesiumFs');
  
  if(!ol3d.getEnabled())
  //if ol3d is true
  {
       //when opening up Cesium I change zoom and center
    const NewView =  new ol.View({
      projection: mercatorProjection,
      center: ol.proj.transform([-80, 20], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 3,
      maxZoom: 15,
      minZoom: 0,  
      }); 
    map.setView(NewView);

    //enable ol3d  
    ol3d.setEnabled(true);


        //Fullscreen Cesium 
        //shows the fullscreen container (set as active) 
        cesiumFsTrigger.classList.add('FsActive');

        let cesiumFsElement = document.getElementById('map');

        //set the Cesium widget fullscreen
        var widgetFsContainer= document.getElementById('cesiumFs');
        
        //adds the Cesium.Fullscreenbutton
        new Cesium.FullscreenButton(widgetFsContainer, cesiumFsElement);    
          
       
  }
  else {

    //if ol3d is false
    ol3d.setEnabled(false)
    map.setView(view);
    const widgetToRemove = document.getElementsByClassName('cesium-button');
    while(widgetToRemove.length > 0){
      widgetToRemove[0].parentNode.removeChild(widgetToRemove[0]);
    }
       
    cesiumFsTrigger.classList.remove('FsActive');

  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I confirm it can work with Safari,
My main idea is to create a Viewer and add a custom event handler beforeExecute and afterExecute.
In this I have a different behavior for Safari and the others.

For checking if it works.
First get a [test.igc](https://gist.github.com/eltorio/7e085775ae732a472ae3c43cf01a286b) (extension is important) test track.
Next go at https://www.highcanfly.club/trackjoiner and add a "Vol" which is a fly….
After hit "Tracer en 3D", it will create a Cesium Viewer like this and it adds the two custom events:
[Look in the full code for the cesium() method](https://github.com/highcanfly-club/vue-highcanfly/blob/b4772a84a03ef9b6ad9c9540b386b1c46c9b248d/src/components/Cards/CardCesium.vue#L41). It is the method called imediatly after the view is mounted.

```js
         Ion.defaultAccessToken = cesiumConf.token;
        const viewer = new Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
            geocoder: false,
            infoBox: true,
            timeline: false,
            animation: false,
            navigationHelpButton: true,
            sceneModePicker: false,
            baseLayerPicker: this.$auth0.user.value !== undefined,
            terrainProvider: createWorldTerrain(),
            // imageryProvider: new Cesium.OpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
            //   url: 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/'
            // }),
            imageryProvider: new ArcGisMapServerImageryProvider({
                url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer'
            })
        });
        viewer.scene.primitives.add(createOsmBuildings());
        const fullScreenHandler = () => {
            const canvas = viewer.canvas;
            if ('webkitRequestFullscreen' in canvas) {
                canvas['webkitRequestFullscreen']() // Safari
            } else {
                canvas.requestFullscreen();
            }
        }
        viewer.fullscreenButton.viewModel.command.beforeExecute.addEventListener(fullScreenHandler)
        viewer.fullscreenButton.viewModel.command.afterExecute.addEventListener(fullScreenHandler)
```

If you want to see my full code go there:
https://github.com/highcanfly-club/vue-highcanfly/blob/main/src/components/Cards/CardCesium.vue .

Comment: Thanks @albert_tinon, but I am operating in OpenLayers, where I have a series of geojson files projected on a mercator map. My need was to add the functionality of changing to 3d, only for the purpose to visualize layers on the poles in a better way. I know very very little of Cesium and I followed the instruction to change projection reported here  [https://openlayers.org/ol-cesium/](https://openlayers.org/ol-cesium/). However yesterday evening I found the way to add the Cesium.Fullscreenbutton which solved the problem!